# Colocar border-bottom em linha da tabela com css

Tags: html, css

Com tenho o seguinte CSS que coloca uma borda em todas as linha da tabela.

```
.tab_dados tr {
  height: 50px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #D5D5D5;
}
```

Bom tem alguma forma de fazer que com seja colocar a borda em todas as linhas, menos na primeira `TR`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

usa selector `:first-child`

**Mas** terás de usar o selector `not()` para aplicar em todas menos no primeiro filho:

```
.tab_dados tr:not(:first-child) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D5D5D5;
}
```

Ou poderás simplesmente remover a borda do primeiro filho:

```
.tab_dados tr:first-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Por mais que foi considerado a primeira resposta correta, acho que outra solução seria aplicar o border ao `<td>` pois a borda não é aplicada as tables quando não setadas: `table { border-collapse: collapse; }` *WHEREVER*, essa seria uma outra solução.

```css
table tr:not(:first-child) td{
  height: 50px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #D5D5D5;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> Item 11</td>
    <td> Item 12</td>
    <td> Item 13</td>
    <td> Item 14</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td> Item 21</td>
    <td> Item 22</td>
    <td> Item 23</td>
    <td> Item 24</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```